# How to create a loop that allows user to input until they are correct in Python

Tags: python, loops

I'm writing a code for a guessing game where the user can choose a range for the number to be in, the program will choose a random number, and the user can guess the number until they are correct.

I've tried using conditionals and a while loop but I cannot get it to run.

```
if (userGuess > targetNum):

    print "\nToo high\n"

elif (userGuess < targetNum):
        print "\nToo low\n"

else:
        print "\nThat's it! Nice job!\n"
```

This program runs but I need help getting it to loop so that the user can input their guess and get feedback if it's too high or too low until they guess the correct number. Thanks

Comment: add in `while True:` and then add break statement when condition is satisfied.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you break the loop when you get to the success case

```
targetNum = 5
while True:
    userGuess = int(input("Guess Number"))
    if (userGuess > targetNum):
        print("\nToo high\n")
        continue
    elif (userGuess < targetNum):
        print("\nToo low\n")
        continue
    #Break here
    else:
        print("\nThat's it! Nice job!\n")
        break
```

The output might look like

```
Guess Number7

Too high

Guess Number9

Too high

Guess Number12

Too high

Guess Number5

That's it! Nice job!
```

Comment: Thank you! For some reason now it says that elif is invalid syntax. I'm not sure how to fix it. Do you know why this may be happening?

Comment: Updated my code to show you working version hope it is more clear @Liv

Answer (score 0):

add a boolean which will be triggered by the condition

```
wrong = True

while(wrong) : 
  if (userGuess > targetNum):
      print "\nToo high\n"
  elif (userGuess < targetNum):
      print "\nToo low\n"
  else:
      print "\nThat's it! Nice job!\n"
      wrong = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place your IF statements inside a `while True:` loop.

```
userGuess = float(input("What's your guess? "))
targetNum = 10

while True:
    if userGuess > targetNum:
        print ("\n Too high\n")
        userGuess = float(input("What's your guess? "))
    elif userGuess < targetNum:
        print ("\n Too low\n")
        userGuess = float(input("What's your guess? "))
    else:
        print ("\n That's it! Nice job! \n")
        break
```